# Could not resolve proxy: POST (while running curl script for watson document conversion)

Tags: curl, ibm-watson

I'm running a curl script for HTML document conversion with a HTML file config. Below is the code:

```
curl -x POST -u "Username":"Password" -F "config=@config.json" -F "file=@example.html;type=text/html" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/document-conversion/api/v1/index_document?version=2015-12-15"
```

I'm getting error  -  `Could not resolve proxy: POST`. If anyone could help on this please?

Note - I have `curl 7.46` installed

Answer (score 69):

I am learning curl recently and encountered this as well. Actually, the reason is that the `-x` should be replaced by `-X`.

Comment: I guess this should be the accepted answer, helped me to correct my typo, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You error seems like one proxy config problem.

Try use `--noproxy` flag:

Example:

```
curl --noproxy 127.0.0.1 +your POST
```

Or try set your proxy, like my example:

```
curl --proxy <[protocol://][user:password@]proxyhost[:port]> +your POST
```

Obs.: Use the specified HTTP proxy. If the port number isn't specified, will be 1080 for default.

Comment: Thanks, After resolving the proxy error ., nowI am getting an error for Content-Type. Below is the error which I am getting- 
 "code" : 400,
  "error" : "Error from server at WATSONRETRIEVE_CLOUDSEARCH: ERROR: [doc=58afeff9-b919-4ab1-bfb3-a060c8e93131] unknown field 'Content-Type'"

Comment: Hello @Rex ... the error you are getting now seems to be related to other problem . Therefore, you should ask a new question, and accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score -3):

1. download and install GIT
2. write the command curl -X, for example `curl -X POST "yourwebsite.js"`